# Recovering data from a broken Hitachi drive?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, hardware-failure

I have a HITACHI Deskstar ([this one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822145304&cm_re=HITACHI_Deskstar-_-22-145-304-_-Product)) 1TB drive. I think I broke the circuit board while unplugging it. When I plugged it back in, my BIOS no longer detects it. I tried it in another computer, which also failed to detect it (after a slight hang while trying to do so during POST).

I'm wondering if there's any way I can recover the data from it (without paying one of those data recovery services thousands of dollars). For example, if I bought another drive of the exact same make/model, could I swap the magnetic disks? I have another drive I can transfer the data to, so if both disks end up dead after the process, that's fine; I just care about the data.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** turns out the drive isn't totally dead... While the BIOS will hang at boot time, if I hot-plug it once Windows is started, it works fine (note I wasn't trying to boot from it). So if anyone else is having a drive failure try that. I have no idea *why* it would be (consistently) doing that, but at least it's working.

Comment: Have you tried placing the disk in a USB enclosure to see if it get detected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data recovery is not thousands.

Its $499 for up to 3TB

http://www.lowcostrecovery.com/pricing.html

.

Same make and model drive may not have the same PCB, they have to be an exact match.
http://www.harddrive-repair.com/hard-drive-parts.html

.

Parts
http://www.onepcbsolution.com/

http://www.hddzone.com/

http://www.hdd-parts.com/